Which significance test to use for a difference of means? How to be sure?
[Updated] I have two data sets containing all official recorded games played in the USA for this one sport.  One data set is for the women's teams and the other for the men's teams.  I'm trying to test whether or not the men's teams, on average, score more points, and I believe they do.
From the data sets I limit the games to those of the past twenty years and to only tournament games.  This gives a women's sample of about 200 games and a men's sample of about 300 games.  I assume that the games are independent of each other within genders and not paired between genders.
Since the sample sizes are greater than 40 or considered "large," I can use a $z$-test on the difference between the means of the two populations.
Question: Is that the correct hypothesis test to choose here based on the independence and large sample sizes?
One point of confusion is the underlying assumption of normality.  What, exactly, is assumed to have a normal distribution when the sample size is large?  The $z$-values I would get from a bunch of samples?  Or is it the distribution of the points per game per gender that is assumed to be normal?
Significance level: 5%
Null hypothesis: No difference between the means.
Alternative hypothesis: Mean score for men is greater than mean score for women, so difference is greater than 0.
I calculate the sample means and variances to use in the calculation of the test statistic value $z$. I get that $z = 2.81$.
To find the $p$-value, I use a table to compute 1 - $\Phi(2.81)$ and get 0.0025.
Since 0.0025 < 0.05 I reject the null hypothesis.
Question: Is my thinking correct?
Update 2: Histograms of the points scored for the women in the sample of 200 games does not look normal.  Neither does the men's scores.
UPDATE 3: Given the lack of normality for the population distributions I went with a Wilcoxon rank sum test.  This successfully solves the problem. ... The stinky part is not completely understanding why the normality is required in the first place.  I feel like I need a more thorough textbook or something.


If your simulation size is small enough that you're not confident
which side of your chosen $\alpha$ $p$ falls on, you should consider a substantially  larger simulation size. Where time permits I tend to use much larger simulations. 2. Not that it matters but you should clarify whether this is a permutation test or a bootstrap test. 3. One thing to beware of is if average scores change over time (as defensive vs offensive strategies evolve, say) but the proportion of games played by females changes at the same time, you could end up attributing to gender an effect that is due to time.


@Glen_b For 2, I'm not clear on that myself.  I don't think it's bootstrapping since I'm not resampling.  I started with all of the recorded games, then selected only tournament games played after a certain date to get a good sample.  Then I simulate/replicate a sample of the same size 5000 times, but I think each replicate sample is made up by R and not chosen with replacement or something from the original list of all games.

"Then I simulate/replicate a sample of the same size 5000 times" It is unclear what that means. How do you simulate?

For the larger picture, you say "my learning feels so hodge podge".  Well, don't rely on YouTube videos!  If you want to self-study, OK. That's harder than taking a class, but OK. So, read books. I wrote a blog post on Medium that might help.

@Roland I'm using the infer library in R and the generate() function with type = "permute".  I think this creates a replicate/simulation sample of the same size by permuting the response variable, which in this case is the scores/games/rows.  The explanatory variable would be the gender of the teams in the game.

@Glen_b I think R is not making up the numbers as I thought in a previous comment.  It's merely permuting the scores with replacement.  See my comment to Roland. Learning R here too ...

@PeterFlom I'm studying probability from a textbook, where I know one of the authors from my alma mater, so I'm able to ask him questions.  Simultaneously, I'm working through an interactive video series on stats and data analysis through R assuming no background.  I own Freedman & Pisani but have not yet started it :)  Thanks for the link!

resampling with replacement (not permuting) sounds like a bootstrap.

Seems to me that this is a setting where the hypothesis test might be the worst possible analysis to apply. Is there (was there) really any expectation that men's and women's teams would score the same? Characterise the scores and any differences rather than 'test' an uninteresting null hypothesis.

You do not provide enough detail on the scores for anyone to provide you with useful advice on the application of the z-test to your data. Some sports have large fractions of scores of zero, and their means would only start to have approximately normality with samples much larger than the rule of thumb that you mention.

@MichaelLew I'm self studying, so I was given these hypotheses from the book.  What should be normal - the scores themselves or the means of the scores found by taking many samples?

See here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/141314/question-about-normality-assumption-of-t-test

I'd be more worried than you seem to be about independence. They're the same teams!

@JeremyMiles We are told that they are to be considered independent.  I think the point of the problem is to choose the correct hypothesis test.

Fair enough. I wonder why people make up problems with obvious flaws, when it's easy to make up problems that don't have flaws.

One problem is that you are placing many assumptions into your null hypothesis model, like assuming the games to be independent, or like assuming heterogeneity (you don't express this explicitly in your question, but it is implicit when you consider a single difference of means). So, when you happen to falsify your null hypothesis with a small p-value, then this becomes ambiguous. There are multiple alternative hypotheses that could be more plausible, it is not only the difference in means, but also the assumptions that can be wrong...

... when the null hypothesis is falsified, then it also matters how sure you are about the assumptions integrated into the null hypothesis. Which part of the null model was wrong? To be honest, I am not sure whether you can be sure in this situation, that it was all due to the effect that you intended to measure. False believes about the distribution might also give false evaluations of p-values.
